# Custom post type archive 404 after renaming post type in CPT UI (the actual posts are working, cache cleared)

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have renamed a custom post type on my website using CPT UI.

Things I have done:
1. I have checked the "Migrate posts to newly renamed post type" box when renaming.
2. I have cleared the browser page and the WP cache in the admin bar.
3. I have flushed the permalinks several times.
4. I have renamed the archive template file to use the new name (though as far as I understand this shouldn't matter in the 404 issue, it could have just displayed as archive.php or index.php)

However. The actual post with the new type name display correctly (example.com/new-post-type-name/post-name), but the post archive page gives me a 404 (example.com/new-post-type-name).

What can I be doing wrong and in what direction do I look? I have tried searching here and on Google, but for the most part I see advice to clear the cache and to flush the permalinks which I've already done.

Thank you very much in advance, I am feeling really confused at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be simple.

In the custom post type settings in CPT UI there's a "has archive" setting where you can specify the archive URL. And mine was set to the old post type name. I thought that mine was set to blank which would have meant using the default (new post name) for the URL, but it turned out it specifically said the old name. So don't forget to check that if you're in my shoes.